# "De" suivi d'un nom propre en "De"

Tags: noms-propres, contractions, de

Doit-on plutôt dire

> la formule de De Moivres

ou

> la formule de Moivres

Et

> la règle de D'Alembert

ou

> la règle d'Alembert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Les particules<sup>1</sup> ne prennent pas de majuscule (sauf quand une autre règle l'impose comme la majuscule en début de phrase). Cependant, quand elles sont précédées de la préposition *de*, il est admis d'autoriser la majuscule pour éviter la confusion qui s'ensuivrait<sup>2</sup> :

> [la formule de De Moivre](http://dictionnaire.sensagent.leparisien.fr/Formule%20de%20de%20Moivre/fr-fr/)
>
> la formule de de Moivre
>
> la règle de D'Alembert
>
> [la règle de d'Alembert](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A8gle_de_d%27Alembert)

Les ouvrage de mathématiques et de physique omettent cependant parfois la particule en fonction de l'usage établi et écrivent :

> [la formule de Moivre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formule_de_Moivre)

<sup>1</sup><sub>Sauf en Belgique pour les patronymes d'origine néerlandaise où **De**
est un article défini.</sub>
<sup>2</sup><sub>C'est même une recommandation de l'Académie française.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Pour autant que je sache, il faut conserver la particule, mais sans majuscule :

> La formule de de Moivre.

et

> La règle de d'Alembert.